# error using django filter he option of multiple choices when searching'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm using django filter to do search on my system, and it's working.
the problem is that I have two fields with multiple choices and when I go to the search page, does not appear the multiple choices, only a normal field box and looking for it does not appear the results.
wanted to add the number of multiple choices

I'm Brazilian and I'm using google translator for this question, I'll summarize it in a sentence: 'I need in pet_aceitos, the option of multiple choices when searching'

models.py

```
PETN_CHOICES = (
    ('Cachorro Pequeno Porte','Cachorro Pequeno Porte'), ('Cachorro Médio Porte','Cachorro Médio Porte'),('Cachorro Grande Porte','Cachorro Grande Porte'),('Gato','Gato'), ('Pássaros', 'Pássaros'), ('Peixes','Peixes'), ('Reptéis','Reptéis'), ('Roedores','Roedores')
)

class Negocio(models.Model):
   pet_aceitos = MultiSelectField(max_length=255, choices=PETN_CHOICES)
```

forms.py

```
   class NegocioForm(UserCreationForm):
 pet_aceitos = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
          widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=PETN_CHOICES, )
class Meta:
          model = User
```

filter.py

```
import django_filters
from django import forms
import django_filters
from .models import (
    Negocio,

)

class NegocioFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):


    class Meta:
        model = Negocio
        fields = ['cidade', 'estado', 'pet_aceitos', 'tipo', 'telefone']
```

user_list.html

```
{% block main %}
    <form method="get">
      {{ filter.form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <ul>
    {% for negocio in filter.qs %}
      <li><img src="{{negocio.foto.medium.url}}"class="rounded-circle" width="50" height="50"> - {{ negocio.cidade }} - {{ negocio.estado }}- {{ negocio.pet_aceitos }} - {{ negocio.tipo }} - {{ negocio.telefone }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endblock %}
```